# Php7.0 is installed, but service doesn't appear in services list

Tags: php, services

I have install php7.0 and some it extention, but when I type 
"sudo service php7.0 restart", what I found is

```
"Failed to restart php7.0.service: Unit php7.0.service failed to load: No such file or directory."
```

and I check in service list `sudo service --status-all` and I was not found "php7.0"

is there anyone can help?

Comment: are you sure that the service should be named `php7.0` ? .... have you tried any other names?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi

Comment: use sudo service apace2 restart and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

You expect it to run on apache? Then you need to install apache2 with libapache2-mod-php7.0 and then you start it with apache2. If what you want to control is if php7.0 will be enabled on apache2 then I think what you need to use is **a2enmod** and **a2dismod**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a PHP service (apart from a never ending PHP script you would have created yourself).

The closest thing to a service that runs PHP is *PHP-FPM* which is available as `php7.0-fpm` package.

Other services are webservers (eg. *Apache*) as *eftshift0* already answered.